# PHP Doctrine - YAML syntax help. Default value for many to many relationship?

Tags: php, doctrine, yaml, relationships

I have the following YAML schema for organising users in Doctrine:

```
Person:
  tableName: people
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true 
    firstname:
      type: string
      notnull: true
      lastname:
      type: string
      notnull: true
User:
  inheritance:
  extends: Person
    type: column_aggregation
    keyField: type
    keyValue: 1
Userdetails:
  columns:
    person_id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
    password:
      type: string
      notnull: true
  relations:
    User:
      foreignType: one
      local: person_id
      onDelete: CASCADE
      onUpdate: CASCADE
Group:
  tableName: groups
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    name:
      type: string
      notnull: true
UserGroup:
  columns:
    group_id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
      person_id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
  relations:
    User:
      foreignType: many
      local: person_id
    Group:
      foreignType: many
```

Basically, any people who are users will belong to one or more groups.
Is there any way to add new users to a particular group by default?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I must admin, that I'm not in the most recent Doctrine version anymore, but since its records need a default constructor I think it should be sufficient to load the default group from the database in the users constructor

```
class User extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->groups[] = Doctrine::getTable('Group')->findByName('DefaultGroup');
    }
}

$blauser = new User();
$blauser->save(); // Will save the user with the default group
```

Depending on your architecture you might want to consider to put that initialisation into your controller, too.